# How do I set an item in a DropDownList as the default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How do I set an item in a DropDownList as the default value in ASP.NET?

```
SomeDropDownList.DataSource =GetSomeStrings();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Set the `SelectedValue` to the value you want as the default `DropDownList.SelectedValue = "value"`. This is very simple but will result in an error if the dropdown already has a `SelectedValue`
2. Set the actual item `DropDOwnList.Items.FindByValue("value").Selected = true;` which should not result in an error in case there already is a selected item.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the DropDownList to the data source, and then set the SelectedValue:

```
someDropDownList.DataSource = GetSomeStrings();
someDropDownList.DataBind();
someDropDownList.SelectedValue = "default value";
```

You could also select the default item by index, using the SelectedIndex property:

```
someDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```